# How to make calculations between RDD rows?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a Spark RDD like this:

```
[(1, '02-01-1950', 2.8), (2, '03-01-1950', 3.1), (3, '04-01-1950', 3.2)]
```

And I want to calculate the increase (by percentage) between sequential rows. For example, from row 1 to row 2 the increase of value is 110.7% `((3.1/2.8)*100)`, and so on.

Any suggestions on how to make calculations between rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the RDD with the same RDD that have the keys shifted by 1:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, '02-01-1950', 2.8), (2, '03-01-1950', 3.1), (3, '04-01-1950', 3.2)])

rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))
rdd3 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0]+1, x[2]))

rdd4 = rdd2.join(rdd3).mapValues(lambda r: r[0]/r[1]*100)

rdd4.collect()
# [(2, 110.71428571428572), (3, 103.2258064516129)]
```